# How to set chat room password in Prosody XMPP server?

Tags: xmpp, chat, chatroom, multiuserchat, prosody-im

I'm new to Prosody XMPP server. i have setup the server and can create chat rooms. Now I wonder how to restrict particular chat room to given set of users.

Suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Prosody but I can help in XMPP specs to find (just search for namespaces in Prosody code).

However you are asking for 3/4 differents task

1) Restrict to "given set of users": if Prosody has **Groups**, you can add any number of groups to your **groupchat**

2) About password: while creating a groupchat you can set as configuration:

```
"muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom" -> true
"muc#roomconfig_roomsecret" -> "mypassword"
```

3) About restricted join: while creating (or updating of course) a **groupchat** configuration, you have to set:

```
"muc#roomconfig_membersonly" -> true;
```

and while you are inviting an user you have to:
1) `grantVoice` (it's optional but some implementations can require it)
2) `grantMembership` or something you like in "XEP-0045: Multi-User-Chat - 5.1 Roles"

Not all specs are supported by servers so you need to check what Prosody supports and how, but searching for namespaces make search shorter ;)

Docs:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html

Answer (score 1):

No need to use passwords, just make room "members only" - only people who get invite can access that room

Comment: Is it server side setting or client side setting? thanks!

Comment: It's room setting which persists on server, can be changed by room "administrator" from client